# How to use mergeMap to merge two observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

How to use mergeMap to combine existing observable with one from HTTP post response.

I have `resultSource = this.httpClient.get<any>(this.SERVER_URL);` The resultSource is array of JSON.

Next, I would like to merge this resultSource with JSON response from `this.httpClient.post<any>(this.SERVER_URL, formData)`.

I have attached code snippet below for more clarity.

```
export class ApiService {
  SERVER_URL = 'some URL';
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public resultSource = this.httpClient.get<any>(this.SERVER_URL);

  public upload(formData): any {
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.SERVER_URL, formData).pipe(
      tap(mergeMap(response => this.httpClient.get<any>(this.SERVER_URL))));
    }
}
```

resultSource is used as source in Angular Material Table.

Comment: There are several excellent resources available with a quick google search. What specifically is the issue you're seeing when you try it out? Please include code or relevant documentation.

Comment: I could not find any that suits my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to create a private field array of observable "resultSource" then call your http get request in the constructor and add result of get request into the "resultSource". Make getter or public method which return the private field value as an observable. In an upload function adds response data in the "resultSource" that you receive upon post request. 
Below you will find the link to one of the article that I found and I hope it will help you
[angular-observable-data-services](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-observable-data-services)